# Get documents created in date range where specific field never seen before

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a ElasticSearch index named 'transactions'. It contains a lot of e-shop transactions and especially some fields "userId" and "txId".

Now I would like to query two things from my ES cluster:

- List of "monthly new customers" => The one that have made a transaction in a specific time range but where their userId has never been seen before
- List of "regulars customers" => The one that made at least 2 transactions in a specific time range.

I'm getting stuck at having that kind of time-contextualized but also not contextualized data.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your mapping and sample data with expected result

Comment: This should be 1 timestamp field (user creation) + 1 nested fields (list of transacation of this user, with the date on each)